# Custom filter for WordPress loop with multiple post types

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a WordPress website where I would like to display some pages along with posts in the blog index. The tricky condition is that, that `WP_Query` should return all 'posts', but when it comes to 'pages' it should fetch only pages with particular parent id's say parent ids being 1,2,3 etc.

I would like to know if its possible to accomplish this in one `WP_Query` while preserving the WordPress loops and functions like `have_posts()`, paging functions like `previous_posts_link()` etc. Is this possible to do? could someone point me in the right direction? Please let me know if any more information is required is from my end or if anything is unclear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution with a bit more research using the plugin - [wp-combine-queries](https://github.com/birgire/wp-combine-queries)

Sample code as follows

```
//------------------------
// Children pages query #1
//------------------------
$pages = [
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'post_parent__in' => [
        1944,1962,1343,1377,909,952 // Post id's of parents
     ],
    'posts_per_page' => -1
];

//-------------------
// All Posts Query #2
//-------------------
$posts = [
   'post_type'      => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => -1
];

//---------------------------
// Combined queries #1 + #2:
//---------------------------
$args = [
    'paged'               => get_query_var( 'paged', 1 ),
    'combined_query' => [        
        'args'   => [ $pages, $posts ],
        'union'  => 'UNION',
    ]
];

//---------
// Output:
//---------
$posts_to_display = new WP_Query( $args );
```